# Dijkstra complexity analysis using adjacency list and priority queue?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

I just got to look at the Implementation of Dijkstra using adjacency list and priority queue. The time complexity is $O(E\log V +V)$, I tried looking for the proof but couldn't find one. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's algorithm visits every node once ($=O(V)$), and tries to relax all adjecent nodes via the edges. Therefore it iterates over each edge exactly twice ($=O(E)$), each time accessing the priority queue up to two times in $O(\log V)$.

Therefore the complexity is $O(E \log V + V)$.

For a proof of the correctness, just look it up at any basic algorithms book, like CLRS.

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify that I believe the $O(E\log V+V)$ runtime requires a special priority queue implementation: the fibonacci heap. I'm just adding this clarification because I couldn't understand the $O(E\log V+V)$ analysis since I had never heard of the fibonacci heap (currently taking data structures and we never mentioned it). Apparently it has some pretty crazy runtime analyses! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap

A standard n-ary heap would lead to a $O((E+V)\log V)$ runtime.

The proof I'm used to (it would work with fibonacci heap just substitute the better runtimes for the priority queue operations) is what Jakube showed.

Every vertex is pushed into the queue when it is first discovered and popped off when it is processed. This gives $O(V \cdot \log (V))$ ($O(\log V)$ `insert()` and `removeMin()` since in the worst case the queue has almost all of our vertices).

Then every edge will be checked twice. In the worst case, one of those times will be one where we update a distance to another node. So we get $O(E \cdot \log V)$ for all of those.

Combined you end up with $O(V \cdot \log (V) + E \cdot \log V)$ which becomes $\boxed{O((V + E) \log V)}$

With the fibonacci heap the insertions and `removeMin()` calls (the pops) are amortized O(1) and the `decreaseKey()` call is still $O(\log V)$ as far as I understand, so the vertex part goes from $O(V \log V)$ to $O(V)$ and the edge analysis stays the same, hence you get the runtime quoted in the question and selected answer.

Comment: As mentionned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time), a Fibonacci heap can provide $\mathcal{O}(|E| + |V|\log |V|)$.

Comment: Yep, I note that in my original post. Crazy big O analysis on those fibonacci heaps. As far as I recall they aren't used often in practice though because they have pretty hefty constant factors.